# Date/Timestamp column in DBeaver (SQL Client) but I only want the date (using a CSV file)

Tags: sql, date, time, dbeaver

I'm fairly rookie when it comes to SQL but as of recent I've been having to use it in it's basic form to do very simple tasks like only recalling relevant columns from a table etc.

I'm currently using DBeaver as my SQL Client and for this example I'm tapping straight into a CSV, no problems there. The data I'm working with is transaction data and the table is structured as follows

[image: Example of Data]

My problem is that the data is in 15 minute intervals whereas I need a value per day per store per metric (I.E. in the image example, it would return "Site" = 101 - "Metric" = FOODSER3 - "Date" = 2020-08-09 - "Value" = 6.0000)

Firstly, is this possible

Secondly, if so then please could someone let me in on the secret of how and maybe an explanation as to what the resolution is and why so that I can really understand what's going on.

I'm fairly proficient in Javascript and VBA, but so far SQL defeats me at every hurdle.

Comment: This depends on the actual DBMS you are using. Every DBMS has different was of doing that. In standard SQL you could e.g. use `cast("Date" as DATE)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks for your reply. Where would this go in the query, does it come after Select or after From?

Comment: It goes into the list of column in the SELECT part.

Comment: @Morley89 . . . DBeaver is a GUI interface.  *It is not a database.*. You should tag with the database you are using, which would typically have a name such as MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The structure of such a query is aggregation.  Date/time functions are notoriously dependent on a database, but the idea is:

```
select cast(date as date), site, metric, sum(value)
from t
group by cast(date as date), site, metric;
```